# Using Grape to create an API with just Ruby objects instead of a database or Rails

Tags: ruby, rack, grape-api

I am trying to use [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) to create an API using only Ruby objects.  I do not want to use a database/Rails/ActiveSupport/etc -- just Rack, Ruby, and Grape.

I have defined a class for a `Directory` that I want to interact with through the API.  So `Directory#sort_by("last_name")` returns JSON data with a list of `People` objects in my `Directory`. I also have a method `Directory#create_person(attributes)` that takes a string and uses it to add `Person` objects to the `Directory`.  The directory is populated with people upon creation.

I am new to working with Rack and Grape, so I'm not sure where/how to create my `Directory` object and have it accessible through the GETs/POSTs in my Grape API class.  Using a class variable inside this class appears to work, i.e.,:

```
module API
  class DirectoryAPI < Grape::API
    format 'json'

    @@directory = Directory.new("1.txt", "2.txt", "3.txt")

    get 'last_name' do
      @@directory.sort_by("last_name")
    end
  end
end
```

but using class variables just seems wrong.  Is there any better/cleaner way to create my `Directory` object? Perhaps inside my `config.ru` file? Or could I do it through a class method inside of `Directory` somehow?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a [singleton](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html):

> Usually singletons are used for centralized management of internal or external resources and they provide a global point of access to themselves.

Unfortunately, Ruby just doesn't play well with singletons. But you can use a "class consisting of only class methods," the second strategy advocated in this [article](https://practicingruby.com/articles/ruby-and-the-singleton-pattern-dont-get-along).

I believe that you are working on a coding challenge that I completed a few months ago. In my answer, I used a "class consisting of only class methods" called `API::Store`. Here's the output from `rspec -fd`:

```
API::Store
  ::add
    adds record to store
    appends data line to file
  ::has_line?
    instantiates a record from the data line
    without the record in the store
      should equal false
    with the record in the store
      should equal true
  ::new
    should raise NoMethodError
  ::records
    with original file
      on initial access
        should eq Records
      on subsequent access
        should eq Records
    when file replaced
      should eq OtherRecords

Finished in 0.07199 seconds (files took 2.68 seconds to load)
9 examples, 0 failures
```

Note that `Store` can't be instantiated; it throws a `NoMethodError` if you try. That's not a problem, though. In the Grape endpoint you can call `Store.records` to access the data.

As for sorting the records, this should be done in another class. Why should a `Store` or a `Directory` be sorting the data in its files?

Finally, you asked where to do the initial preparation (not initialization, of course). You can prepare your singleton in `config.ru`, so that it is ready when the application starts:

```
# config.ru

# load application code here

file = File.open('data/records.txt', 'a+')
at_exit { file.close }

API::Store.file = file
run API::Base
```

The challenge's [instructions](https://reverb.com/page/dev-challenge) say "You may use any resources you need to complete it," so presumably, asking on Stack Overflow is allowed. If you are doing this challenge for a job application, please do mention so when you ask questions, because it's only fair for those answering to be informed. It would be wise to also mention at your interview that you got help on SO. Good luck, and happy coding.

Comment: This looks good, but I don't think it is answering the question. OP is asking about code in the controller, not how to create a data management class. What you are missing is showing how it would be used in the controller. Perhaps a line like `Store.records` in place of the OP's line `@@directory.sort_by("last_name")`?

Comment: Thank you, @NeilSlater. I believe the OP's essential question was not, "What should I do in my controller?" but "How should I access my data?" Nonetheless, I edited my answer to get straight to the point, both about singletons and about being forthcoming with us about the coding challenge.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see with your example is not the use of class variables exactly, but instantiating your data inline in the API controller code. Ideally the data should be more self-contained, so you can access the exact same data from other places in your code. If you make an API similar to a light-weight data access module, then you will be using a familiar pattern in your route controllers - also it will become easy to migrate to using SQL or other data store if and when you need to.

There are lots of valid approaches, but I might create a new singleton object to represent your data source, and connect that to your hard-coded data as if it were tables. The end result here would feel a little like using Sequel (but you could follow any other pattern that you prefer):

**inline_data.rb**

```
module InlineDB
  TABLES = Hash[
     :directory => Directory.new("1.txt", "2.txt", "3.txt")
  ]

  def self.[] table_name
    TABLES[table_name]
  end
end
```

**app.rb**

```
require_relative 'inline_data' # actual path may be more structured
module API
  class DirectoryAPI < Grape::API
    format 'json'

    get 'last_name' do
      InlineDB[:directory].sort_by("last_name")
    end
  end
end
```